# OOM | Not able to query Spark Temporary table

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 4.5 million records in a Hive table. 
My requirement is to cache this table as a temporary table through Spark thrift server, beeline so that Tableau can query the temporary table and generate reports.

I have 4 node clusters, each node has 50g RAM and 25 vCores. I'm using HDP2.3 with Spark 1.4.1

### Issue:

I'm able to cache the table in less than a minute and able to get the correct count from temp table. But the problem is when I try to execute a select query (using beeline, same spark sqlContext) with one column, hitting OOM error.

Tried below configurations without any luck:

1)    sudo ./sbin/start-thriftserver.sh --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.bind.host=10.74.129.175 --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=10002 --master yarn-client --driver-memory 35g --driver-cores 25 --num-executors 4 --executor-memory 35g --executor-cores 25

```
$SPARK_HOME./bin/beeline> cache table temp1 as select * from hive_table;
```

set below config in spark-default file – 
    spark.driver.maxResultSize 20g
    spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max 2000mb
    spark.rdd.compress true
    spark.speculation true

2)    sudo ./sbin/start-thriftserver.sh --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.bind.host=10.74.129.175 --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=10002 --master yarn-client --driver-memory 35g --driver-cores 5  --num-executors 11  --executor-memory 35g --executor-cores 5

```
$SPARK_HOME./bin/beeline> cache table temp1 as select * from hive_table;
```

set below config in spark-default file – 
    spark.driver.maxResultSize 20g
    spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max 2000mb
    spark.rdd.compress true
    spark.speculation true

As per my understanding, I have enough RAM in driver machine and should be able to bring the result of select to driver.

Comment: Can you please provide a bit more info about the general structure and in particular the query